# Mongodb: sharing a database between two computers

Tags: mongodb

I created a database using MongoDB on Computer 1.
I am trying to load this DB from Computer 2.
Could you please help me to do that ?

I tried to set the --dbpath (data\db) in a shared disk F:\ but Computer 2 is not able to recognize the data.

Comment: There are so many variables involved here. Access, Mongo version etc. Can you copy the complete data to the 2nd computer and try there first? If it works then we will be sure that it is something to do with profile etc and not a data issue.

Comment: Do you need only data from Computer 1 or do you want to copy entire mongod config/dbs?

Comment: I tried to do that and Computer 2 is not able to read the database because it has been created by another host.
MongoDB versions are both 3.2 @Abhinav

Comment: @necromos, I need to be able to access the same database and modify it from Computer 2 without using internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the mongo cluster from any other node, for that you need to know the port on which the config-server is running on node (Computer) 1.
The config-server can be started using the following command. Ideally there should be 3 config servers running on a system so, I am updating the steps to take that into account.

`<path-to-mongo>/bin/mongod --configsvr --port <port-1> --dbpath ./shardedcluster/cfg0 --fork`

`<path-to-mongo>/bin/mongod --configsvr --port <port-2> --dbpath ./shardedcluster/cfg1 --fork`

`<path-to-mongo>/bin/mongod --configsvr --port <port-3> --dbpath ./shardedcluster/cfg2 --fork`

**Issue:** No shards found. Earlier, I assumed that no shards were necessary to setup this kind of system. However, to overcome this issue you can create a shard server, and initialize it as follows.

`<path-to-mongo>/bin/mongod --shardsvr --replSet a --dbpath ./shardedcluster/a0 --port <shard-port> --fork --smallfiles --oplogSize 50`

To initialize the Shard, follow the steps below.

`<path-to-mongo>/bin/mongo --port <shard-port>`

Then, run the command
`rs.initiate()`

Assuming on Computer 2 you have copied the MongoDB executable. Run the Following command on Computer 2

`<path-to-mongodb>/bin/mongos --configdb <C1-IP>:<port-1>,<C1-IP>:<port-2>,<C1-IP>:<port-3> --port 27017`

Then run (on Computer-2),

`<path-to-mongodb>/bin/mongo --port 27017`

27017 is default port, I am using that option just for verbosity.

**Note 1** If the shard initialization error persists 
Run the following command in mongos shell,

`sh.addShard("a/<C1-IP>:<Shard-port>")`

**Note 2** Please, ensure that directory shardedcluster/cfg0, shardedcluster/cfg1, shardedcluster/cfg2, shardedcluster/a exists and have proper write permissions.

To get more details, follow the below link.
http://www.mongodbspain.com/en/2015/01/26/how-to-set-up-a-mongodb-sharded-cluster/

I have given you only the required commands out of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Just to make sure, should I create a server between the two of them or there is an option to create a mongodb server ?

Comment: A single instance of config-server on computer 1 would be fine. Use the following command for that purpose.  `mongod --configsvr --port <port> --dbpath <path-to-data-directory> --fork`

Comment: Thank you.
 
In computer 1 I run : 'Mongod --configsvr --port 51213'.

In computer 2 I run : 'Mongos --configdb 10.2....3:51213 --port 445'.

I get the following problems : bind() error 10013 , shutdown() , failed to open minidumb files error 5.

Yet, on my mongod --configserver, the computer 1 detects the connexion and says it has been ended.

Comment: You Need to provide `--dbpath` as the argument. Please, make sure that the data directory has appropriate write permissions.

Comment: I think I created the connection, now when I open a mongo command, I can't read or modify the database, it says "no shards found " err nbr 70

Comment: If my solution was correct please mark it as answer.

Comment: I did, you can check my new question if you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843798/auto-start-mongos-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, when you need only to copy data but not any configuration of specific DB/collections is [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/). Feel free to take a look at them in mongodb doc.

Comment: Mongodump and mongoimport make copies of the database. I need to have one same database for both computers and be able to modify/add/delete data from both mongods

Answer (score 0):

I found this link more helpful
[https://severalnines.com/blog/developer-s-guide-mongodb-replica-sets][1]

> Summarising the steps given in above link:

1. Start first instance of mongo db using replica set name as follows:

> mongod --replSet replicaSetName --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongo/mongod
>   --port 
>       27017

```
//you can provide any name in place of replicaSetName
```

2. Enable replSet mode for this instance

> ```
> rs.initiate()
> ```

3. Start another instance using the config file location

> mongod --config /etc/mongod-secondary.cfg

Sample mongod-secondary.cfg:

> systemLog:
>       destination: file
>       path: /Users/log2/mongod.log storage:
>       dbPath: /Users/MongoSample/data net:
>       port: 27019
>       bindIp: 127.0.0.1 replication:   replSetName: replicaSetName

replicaSetName should be the same as given in instance one, db path and log path should be different then the instance 1

4. Once started log in to mongo console and execute following command to add the new instance in replica set

> rs.add("127.0.0.1:27019");

Thats it!! 
Please check the link for detailed answer.
It has given easier way to create replica's of mongo db instance, the selected answer is correct but somehow difficult to understand thats why posting it here.