# auto start mongos on windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, autostart

I have a mongodb server shared by two computers.

I want to **auto start** the connexion between them when they reboot.

I created a config file for the mongod computer and it works as a windows service now.

I am not able to create a working config file for the mongos computer though.

This is what I tried :

```
sharding:
    configdb: "192.xxx.50:51213"
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "c:\data\log\mongos.log"
processManagement:
    fork: true
```

And I call it in an administrator command prompt as:

```
sc.exe create MongoDBS binPath= "C:\Program Files\mongodb\server\3.2\bin\mongos.exe 
--service --config=C:\mongodb\mongos.config"
```

The service is created.

Then when I start it:

```
net start MongoDBS
```

I get this error : The service is not responding to the control function.

Comment: is `sc` giving you any output? did you checked event log?

Comment: "\"C:\Program Files\mongodb\server\3.2\bin\mongos.exe\"  shouldn;t be  "C:\Program Files\mongodb\server\3.2\bin\mongos.exe" ?

Comment: I updated the post to show you the response of sc